# Woocommerce: Go to order-pay page via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing an online store with Woocommerce but right now I'm struggling with the following thing: I can go to the cart and checkout page by using the shortcodes but the order-pay page has no shortcode. Has anyone an idea about how to achieve this?

This is basically how I work with shortcodes:

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
    data: { action: 'getShortcode', shortcode: 'cart' },
    success: function( response ){
        // replace content
    }
});
```

functions.php

```
add_action("wp_ajax_getShortcode", "getShortcode");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getShortcode", "getShortcode");

function getShortcode(){    
    echo '<div class="wrapper">';
        echo do_shortcode( '['. $_POST['shortcode'] .']' );
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. The order received page is an [endpoint](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-endpoints-2-1/) and the order received's URL can be generated using `$order->$order->get_checkout_order_received_url();` if you have the order object (which you can always get from the order ID)

Comment: @helgatheviking thanks, but this is not what I was looking for. I know about the endpoints. And the problem is, that this is an endpoint and not available as a shortcode. I think I can't make my own checkout process and have to use the built in.

Comment: As I said, I don't really understand what you are trying to do. If you clarify your goal maybe I can offer something else? `woocommerce_checkout` does appear to still be a working shortcode, but I can't tell if that's for backcompatibility or is still used.